# xlsx-populate - wrong parsing - getting for each sheet the data of the one sheet after it

Tags: javascript, xlsx-populate

I parse a lot of files with `xlsx-populate` library and all works well. Now, I have one file that I get wrong data from parsing, seems I get for each sheet the data of the one sheet after it.

E.g. for `sheet1.cell('A1').value()` I get the data that exists in `sheet2` cell `A1`.
Maybe something wrong with my file but I can't point it.
Any idea what happened to my file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it. In my case there was an unusual sheet (hidden) that didn't counted in the sheets indexes so we get for each sheet the index of the one sheet after it.